# How to write Parameterised Query in .NET Framework 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have below code written in c# with .NET Framework 1.1

```
 SqlCommand cmd;
            string strQuery =
                "INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails (EmployeeID,ReasonOfChange) VALUES (@EmployeeID,@ReasonOfChange)";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value = EmployeeID;
            cmd.Parameters["@ReasonOfChange"].Value = ReasonOfChange;

            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But its giving me error.

The error details is :

**An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@EmployeeID' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@EmployeeID' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.
Source Error:**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

cmd.Parameters["@EmployeeID"].Value = EmployeeID;
```

Could you please help me the correct way to write the query in .NET Framework 1.1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the error message, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem :

I changed the code as :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID",EmployeeID);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReasonOfChange",ReasonOfChange);
```

And also

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery,Connection);
```

Previously **Connection** is missing.

Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Now I have problem while retrieving the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821680/cannot-view-the-saved-data-when-apostrophe-is-entered-in-the-input

as in the above link. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of error? It doesn't look like you've specified a connection to a db for your command to execute against? Though you may just have omitted that from your code snippet...

Answer (score 0):

Place control name or variable name for `EmployeeID` below rather giving column name.

```
>   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", (EmployeeID)textbox.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", (EmployeeID)textbox.text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReasonOfChange", (ReasonOfChange)textbox.text);
```

or  try like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int,15);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReasonOfChange", SqlDbType.NVarChar,15);
```